# Referencing an individual style attribute from layout xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:background="?android:style/Widget.ListView.overScrollFooter" 
        >
```

Left out all the unimportant layout stuff. I'm wondering if it's possible to reference one of the individual attributes of defined in a style?

**Edit for more info:** The default styles and attributes for many widgets are defined by Android, and customized further by phone manufacturers. That's how they can customize how a basic android widget looks. In my example, the footer of a listView will look different on a Samsung phone than on a HTC phone or on a default Google phone.

I would like to grab the attribute defined in the listview style (specifically the overscrollfooter drawable attribute), and use it as a background for one of my views. Technically speaking, I have a programmatic solution for this, but it's clunky, and requires that I repeat that code every time I use this view (which is in a lot of places).

Comment: wat you mean by un-important layout stuff?

Comment: layout_width, layout_height, xlms, etc. all that extra stuff that's irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: so what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I agree, what are you trying to accomplish. Styles and attributes aren't applied [excluding view based defaults] unless you define them. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA - These styles are all defined in the core android framework, and are applied application-wide through the fact that my app uses a theme that is a child of an android-defined theme.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think a style is an all or none kinda of deal. I would place the footer in it's own style and import it into your primary style. That frees it up to be used (alone) in yout LinearLayout.

Comment: Bummer. Manipulating the styles at all isn't possible in my current case since it's one of the android framework styles.